# "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" when trying to print a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found the following code online, added the list created and the attempt to print the length

```
from __future__ import print_function
import socket
import struct
import sys
import os
import webbrowser
import json
import urllib

# We want unbuffered stdout so we can provide live feedback for
# each TTL. You could also use the "-u" flag to Python.

class flushfile(file):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def write(self, x):
        self.f.write(x)
        self.f.flush()

sys.stdout = flushfile(sys.stdout)


def main(dest_name):
    dest_addr = socket.gethostbyname(dest_name)
    port = 33434
    max_hops = 30
    icmp = socket.getprotobyname('icmp')
    udp = socket.getprotobyname('udp')
    ttl = 1
    IPlist = []

    while True:
        recv_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, icmp)
        send_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, udp)
        send_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, ttl)

        # Build the GNU timeval struct (seconds, microseconds)
        timeout = struct.pack("ll", 5, 0)

        # Set the receive timeout so we behave more like regular traceroute
        recv_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, timeout)

        recv_socket.bind(("", port))
        sys.stdout.write(" %d  " % ttl)
        send_socket.sendto("", (dest_name, port))
        curr_addr = None
        curr_name = None
        finished = False
        tries = 1
        while not finished and tries > 0:
            try:
                _, curr_addr = recv_socket.recvfrom(512)
                finished = True
                curr_addr = curr_addr[0]
            except socket.error as (errno, errmsg):
                tries = tries - 1
                sys.stdout.write("* ")

        send_socket.close()
        recv_socket.close()

        if not finished:
            pass

        if curr_addr is not None:
            IPlist.append(curr_addr)
            print(len(IPlist))

        ttl += 1
        if curr_addr == dest_addr or ttl > max_hops:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('google.com')
```

It is sample code to simulate the functionality of `traceroute`.

I am trying to add (by using `append`) all the resulting IP addresses stored in `curr_addr` to a list. I am trying to check the length of the list at that line to be sure it keeps growing.

Every time I run it, I get this error:

```
 1  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "traceroute.py", line 96, in <module>
    main('google.com')
  File "traceroute.py", line 84, in main
    print(len(IPlist))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Do ignore the above line numbers as I have removed commented code out before posting.

Comment: Why are you opening / closing the socket every iteration of the loop?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That portion of the code is not mine. I do not understand it completely and am slowly attempting to. My only code is the list and trying to obtain the length of it. Maybe I should state that in the main post

Comment: Why are you messing around with `sys.stdout` and that `flushfile` stuff instead of just adding `flush=True` to the relevant `print()` calls?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Those were already in the code. At the moment I do not understand the code enough to answer your question.

Comment: In that case, you should be asking the author, as this is not SO's intended purpose.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 the code works as it should. It only gives me the error after I added my own bits (which are 3 lines). I do not see why I should ask the author as I believe it is my own fault at play

Comment: @MathanaSreedaran As my answer indicates, `flushfile` is broken. That's the problem. If you want to fix it, listen to us and heed our advice. If you don't want to fix it, then ask the author. If you don't want to do that either, then delete your file and start from scratch.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thank you once again. No disrespect was intended towards anybody. I was only pointing out certain things in hopes of helping TigerhawkT3 understand where I was coming from.

Comment: I understand. I was just pointing out that, just because `flushfile` was already present when you acquired the code, doesn't mean that it isn't broken.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Ignorance on my part there – apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is unsurprisingly with your `flushfile` class.

The problem is that `flushfile` inherits from `file`, and its `closed` attribute defaults to `True`. Thus, when you try to `print()` to `sys.stdout`, it thinks `sys.stdout` has been closed.

You have several options:

1. **Stop using `flushfile`.** It's broken. As mentioned in the comments, the [`print()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) takes an optional `flush` paramter. Just use it instead:

```
 print("This will be flushed even without a newline", end=None, flush=True)
```

2. **Change the `flushfile` base class from `file` to `object`.** As I said, the `file.closed` property defaults to `True`, and can't be manually set. Empirically, it's good enough for `sys.stdout` to have have just a `write` method if you only want to `print()` to it.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my problem.

Comment: Which option did you choose? I highly recommend option 1. Also, please remember to up-vote any answers that help you, and accept the answer that best solves your problem.

Comment: I went with the first option. Removed flushfile class and replaced all sys.stdout.write() with print()